# get config data from current store not from default config (from admin area)

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, shipping-methods

i want to get config data from current store not from default config so for example if i change Table rates title from "Table Rate" to "Something Else" in main webisite config and save it, i can see these changes also in Default store view and that is ok, but if i want to get this title "Something else" i always get title "Table Rates" i am using this code to check it:

```
$title = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/title',Mage::app()->getStore()); 
            var_dump($title);
            die();
```

and it always prints "Table Rate", i have also tried without 'Mage::app()->getStore())' cause i read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892476/how-to-get-data-from-magento-system-configuration) that "The getStoreConfig() method looks like return self::app()->getStore($store)->getConfig($path);, so it get the same if you don't pass the second param - 'Mage::app()->getStore()'." so can anyone tell me how to get config from main website not from default config?

p.s. i have my own shipping module with all config and cerrier and etc files, table rates is just a sample that is the same thing happens to the table rates also.

Comment: Where are you trying to execute this code?

Comment: long story short, i have an observer that listens event <sales_order_shipment_save_before> (the same event when store admin push "ship" button in order view), and there in function i have these line with var dump and etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You problem is that your code is always executed from admin area. So it it always getting store ID of admin store. Which is `0`.

To change this you have to fetch the store ID from the order and use as a second parameter of `Mage::getStoreConfig()`. So in your method it should look like this:

```
public function salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore($observer)
{
    ...
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $title = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/title', $order->getData('store_id'));
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok i just checked with  $title = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStor‌​eId(); and it printed NULL

Comment: i suppose you are right then

Comment: ok i got store id from my order like this: $oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
      $storeID = $oOrder->getData('store_id');
$title = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/title',Mage::app()->getStore($storeID));

Comment: I guess the order instance is passed to the observer itself so you don't have to load it again. How are you getting the `$orderIncrementId` variable?

Comment: public function salesOrderShipmentSaveBefore($observer)
 {
   $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
      $order = $shipment->getOrder();
      $orderIncrementId=$order->getIncrementId();

Comment: So you can get the store id by just `$order->getData('store_id')`.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which is the result if you use this?

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('carriers/tablerate/title');
```

Comment: it prints "Table Rate"

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
$title = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/tablerate/title');
```

also check, is your cache disabled?

Comment: i already tried this as i mentioned, and yes my cache is disabled, i actually disabled it when i started to do something with magento long long time ago, for just to be sure i flushed it but nothing changes, i get same "Table Rate" printed out on screen